# Transforming source xml to another xml using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am looking at transforming the source input xml to output xml format depending whether the individual record is that of `<Student>` or `<teacher>`

> **input xml**:

```
<staff>
 <record>
    <Student>
      <field name="LastName">Dtext</field>
      <field name="FirstName"></field>
      <field name="Class">5</field>
      <field name="Email">Dtext-user33@nova.com</field>
   </Student>
</record>   
<record>   
   <Student>
    ....
   </Student>
</record> 
<record>
   <Teacher>
      <field name="LastName">Dtext-user35</field>
      <field name="FirstName"></field>
      <field name="Email">Dtext-user35@nova.com</field>
      <field name="Experience">10</field>
       <field name="Qualification"></field>
   </Teacher>
</record>
  ....
  ....
```

> **output xml:**

```
<input>
<add user="Student" >
  <add-value value-name="LastName">
    <value type="string">Dtext</value>
  </add-value>
  <add-value value-name="FirstName">
    <value type="string"></value>
  </add-value>
  <add-value value-name="class">
    <value type="string">5</value>
  </add-value>
  <add-value value-name="Email">
    <value type="string">Dtext-user33@novell.com</value>
  </add-value>
</add>
```

or

```
<input>
<add user="Teacher" >
  <add-value value-name="LastName">
    <value type="string">Dtext-user35</value>
  </add-value>
  ....
```

The below is snippet of code which i'm currently working.For some reason this doesn't work.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="staff">           
                 <xsl:for-each select="staff/record">
                    <xsl:when test="name(./*[1])= 'Student'">
                        <xsl:apply-template select = "Student"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                         <xsl:apply-template select = "Teacher">
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Student">  
    <input> 
      <add user="Student">
        <xsl:for-each select="field[string()]">
         <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
         <add-value value-name="{@name}">
           <value type="string">
             <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
           </value>
         </add-value>
       </xsl:for-each>
       </add>
    </input>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:template match="Teacher">  
    <input> 
      <add user="Teacher">
        <xsl:for-each select="field[string()]">
         <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
         <add-value value-name="{@name}">
           <value type="string">
             <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
           </value>
         </add-value>
       </xsl:for-each>
       </add>
    </input>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What corrections to the code are required for it to work..?

> **EDIT:** Corrected all the silly mistakes made in my code.But still no luck as far as output is concerned.

Comment: Why are there backslashes in the closing tags of your xml input ? `<\record>, <\teacher>` and so on... those should be `</record>, </teacher>`

Comment: There's a couple of errors still : `<xsl:apply-template>` needs to be `<xsl:apply-templates>` (notice the plural!), the `<xsl:apply-template select = "teacher">` element should be closed ( `<xsl:apply-templates select = "teacher" />` ), and shouldn't `<xsl:apply-template select = "student"/>` actually be `<xsl:apply-templates select = "Student" />`? I think XSLT is case-sensitive...

Comment: @Miklos Aubert ,I have made changes to code as u pointed out.Still can't figure out what else is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally had some spare minutes to debug the XSLT using Visual Studio (I strongly suggest you to use an XSLT debugger if you can)

Here's what your XSLT file should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="staff">
          <xsl:for-each select="staff/record">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(./*[1])= 'Student'">
              <xsl:apply-templates select = "Student" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select = "Teacher" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <input>
      <add user="Student">
        <xsl:for-each select="field[string()]">
          <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
          <add-value value-name="{@name}">
            <value type="string">
              <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
            </value>
          </add-value>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </add>
    </input>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Teacher">
    <input>
      <add user="Teacher">
        <xsl:for-each select="field[string()]">
          <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
          <add-value value-name="{@name}">
            <value type="string">
              <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
            </value>
          </add-value>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </add>
    </input>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, other than the errors I had told you about in my comments, you forgot to wrap the `<xsl:when>` and `<xsl:otherwise>` of your `for-each` loop inside an `<xsl:choose>` element.

Comment: ,Thanks for taking your time out and replying. Its working now.